# How to get enum from variable in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

I have some enum for example

```
let variable: String = "SALESMAN"
enum Job
{
   SALESMAN = "Salesman"
   POSTMAN = "Postman"
}
```

and I'm getting from database String variable = "SALESMAN", how can get enum Job.SALESMAN using variable?

Comment: what did you try so far? what research did you do about enums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like that:

```
let variable: String = "SALESMAN"
// Make your enum back value of String type
enum Job : String
{
    case SALESMAN = "Salesman"
    case POSTMAN = "Postman"
}

let job = Job(rawValue: variable.capitalizedString) //capitalizedString - change your variable to Salesman to match your enum back first case
// Note job is an optional value so you need to unwrap it if needed

print("\(job)")
```